# C# LINQ filter IEnumerable<IX> and express as IEnumerable<X:IX>

Tags: c#, linq, interface, casting, ienumerable

Apparently it's not possible to cast `WhereEnumerableIterator<IX>` to `IEnumerable<X:IX>`

```
public interface IX 

public class X1 : IX 
public class X2 : IX

public void Method1(IEnumerable<IX> arg)
{
    var filtered = arg.Where(e => e.GetType() == typeof(X2));
    // filtered will be of type WhereEnumerableIterator<IX>
    Method2(filtered as IEnumerable<X2>);
}

public void Method2(IEnumerable<X2> arg) 
{
    // at runtime arg will be null
}
```

Apparently the CLR is unable to cast `WhereEnumerableIterator<IX>` to `IEnumerable<X2>` and sets result null ( somewhat mysteriously ).

It seems logical that a filter could be applied to `IEnumerable<IX>` and the result expressed as `IEnumerable<X:IX>` ( without actually enumerating ).

But how to do this ?

Comment: I think you can just use `art.OfType<X2>()` do filter an `IEnumerable` based on its type

Comment: To expand on Yeldar's comment `.OfType<X2>()` will return an `IEnumerable<X2>` so no need to do any more casting after that.

Answer (score 6):

It happens, because `filtered` is `IEnumerable<IX>` (even though it contains only items of `X2` after filtering) and cannot be casted directly to `IEnumerable<X2>`.
You could do this and cast your `IEnumerable`:

```
var filtered = arg.Where(e => e.GetType() == typeof(X2)).Cast<X2>();
// filtered will be of type WhereEnumerableIterator<X2> now
Method2(filtered);
```

But you can just use [`Enumerable.OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.7.2) to filter an `IEnumerable` based on the type of its elements:

```
public void Method1(IEnumerable<IX> arg)
{
    var filtered = arg.OfType<X2>();
    Method2(filtered);
}

public void Method2(IEnumerable<X2> arg) 
{

}
```